# Mysql Data source on shared drive on dual boot machine

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, windows-xp

Not sure if this is possible, but here is my set up.

I have a laptop with dual boot on it.

One one partition I have WinXP with MSAccess 2000
On another partition, Ubuntu 10.04, with apache webserver and a Mysql database.
On the third partition I have set up a shared drive between the two OS

I would like to be able to access the Mysql datasource from both OS, so I presume I would need to set it up on the shared partition, but I have no idea how to do that.

I have tried Google, but maybe because of my search terms, I have not even come close to finding out a solution, so I thought I'd try here please.

Thanks
Alexis

Comment: What file system does the WinXP partition use?

Comment: This should help you move it to the shared partition: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-change-the-mysql-data-default-directory.html

Comment: Sorry for the late reply...thanks for the link and I will give that a go...FYI the shared drive is FAT32 I believe...I know it is not NTFS as that won;t work on WinXP & Ubuntu..think I have that the right way round.

Comment: Tried that and got an issue with it...firstly the partition is vfat...not fat32....but now I do not have the correct ownership for the mysql data directory.  Currently the ownership for the shared drive is set to plugdev.   How can I change the new mysql data directory to having an ownership of mysql?  I've tried searching on google, etc, but no joy

Answer (score 0):

**A:** I have just provided an extensive answer to this question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170751/sharing-mysql-data-between-windows-and-linux/310712#310712), in the **Unix & Linux StackExchange**.